# Changing image of kubernetes job

Tags: kubernetes, jobs

I'm working on the manifest of a kubernetes `job`.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: hello-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: hello-image:latest
```

I then apply the manifest using `kubectl apply -f <deployment.yaml>` and the job runs without any issue.

The problem comes when i change the image of the running container from `latest` to something else.

At that point i get a `field is immutable` exception on applying the manifest.

I get the same exception either if the job is running or completed. The only workaround i found so far is to delete manually the job before applying the new manifest.

How can i update the current job without having to manually delete it first?

Comment: Hi, `kubectl set image --help` might works

Comment: @SureshVishnoi from the help:
`Possible resources include (case insensitive):
  pod (po), replicationcontroller (rc), deployment (deploy), daemonset (ds), replicaset (rs)`
So no jobs.

Answer (score 12):

I guess you are probably using an incorrect kubernetes resource . [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) is a immutable Pod that runs to completion , you cannot update it . As per Kubernetes documentation ..

> Say Job old is already running. You want existing Pods to keep running, but you want the rest of the Pods it creates to use a different pod template and for the Job to have a new name. You cannot update the Job because these fields are not updatable. Therefore, you delete Job old but leave its pods running, using kubectl delete jobs/old --cascade=false.

If you intend to update an image you should either use Deployment or Replication controller which supports updates